# Two CollectionViews on one View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to have two collection views on one view controller. There are many posts guiding people through this but I cannot tell what I am doing wrong.

My code is the following,

```
class FeedVC: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionViewProgress: UICollectionView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionViewProgress.dataSource = self
        collectionViewProgress.delegate = self
    }
}

extension FeedVC:  UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if (collectionView == self.collectionView){
            return 10
        }else{
            return 1
        }
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        print("hre")
        if (collectionView == self.collectionView){
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "UnclaimedCVC", for: indexPath) as? UnclaimedCVC {
                cell.configureCell()
                return cell
            }else{
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
        }else if(collectionView == self.collectionViewProgress){
            if let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "InProgressCVC", for: indexPath) as? InProgressCVC {
                cell.configureCell()
                return cell
            }else{
                return UICollectionViewCell()
            }
        }else{
            return UICollectionViewCell()
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        if (collectionView == self.collectionView){
            return 1
        }else{
            return 1
        }

    }
}
```

I am currently getting the error,

> 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with
>   identifier InProgressCVC - must register a nib or a class for the
>   identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: You can also use tags to seperate them. It's really easy to use. Just `if collectionView.tag == 1 {}`. You can either set the tags from storyboard or in code. Your choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `viewDidLoad` put

```
collectionView.register(UnclaimedCVC.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UnclaimedCVC ")

collectionViewProgress.register(InProgressCVC.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InProgressCVC ")
```

If you created them as Xibs

```
 collectionView.register(UINib.init(nibName: "UnclaimedCVC", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "UnclaimedCVC")

 collectionViewProgress.register(UINib.init(nibName: "InProgressCVC", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "InProgressCVC")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a side question to the result of this if you have time. Why does this not keep the cells elements such as the background color that I have set in the Interface Builder?

Comment: Do you change that background color in **cell.configureCell**

Comment: I can and it works fine but anything set in interface builder is not kept

Comment: You can also set cell Identifiers in StoryBoard. Select UICollectionViewCell in StoryBoard, go to attributes inspector and enter your identifier under first section "Collection Reusable View"